# "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter" with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx

I have a site which uses WebForms. It has a service which used to work, but my host recently migrated the site to a new server. The DB connections are working but my asmx service is now broken.

I have this signature:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public string GetJarLabel(string type, string serialized)
{
```

Which I'm calling with this jQuery:

```
var requestData = {
            "type":  "jam",
            "serialized": JSON.stringify(data)
};
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Labels.asmx/GetJarLabel",,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            error: function(xhr, status, ex) {
                ...snip
            },
            success: function(r) {
                ...snip
            }
        });
```

[image]

The request seems to be submitted as far as I can tell, but the service responds `500: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'type'.` I've tried switching to GET, stringifying, not stringifying but nothing works. I'm sure this worked before the migration but can't see how that would have affected it.

Comment: I'm not convinced  ASMX WebMethods can accept JSON as input. They can return it, but not sure they can accept it. Try this: remove `processData: false,` and change `data: JSON.stringify(lblData),` to just `data: lblData,`. jQuery will then url-encoded the data parameters for you automatically.

Comment: P.S. In the code above I don't know if it's a typo but you send `lblData` to the server, but it's not defined. You defined `requestData` but that isn't used. I'm assuming it's just a mistake here, not your real code?

Comment: OTOH if you say this used to work...and it's down to something on a new server, then what changes were made between the servers? Did you ask the hosting company for a list of differences with the new server? Perhaps there's a different version of something somewhere. Although it seems quite strange that it would affect something as specific as this. Maybe your code is running on a different version of .NET or something, that's all I can think.

Comment: @ADyson The lblData/requestData was a typo, I merged two methods to post this. I originally omitted `processData`

Comment: " I originally omitted processData" . Ok and did you also omit the JSON.stringify() at the same time? The two things go together really. You've got such a simple structure here that you don't really particularly to send it as JSON (after all, you're hiding the complex data inside the "serialised" string)

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see your ajax call. You're stringfying something called lblData. What is that? Thats not what your are declaring above. Try passing `requestData` instead.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Labels.asmx/GetJarLabel",,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(lblData),
        error: function(xhr, status, ex) {
            ...snip
        },
        success: function(r) {
            ...snip
        }
    });
```

I'm presuming that whatever `lblData` is, it doesn't have a definition for `type`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I merged two methods to simplify the code for posting. I've corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on a different machine from home today (was previously at work). It seems work have some kind of weird outbound proxy setup which is interfering with requests. I guess the lesson is to try over a VPN from a different country or a phone.